# Examples of context-free grammars with worst-case complexity

Tags: algorithm-analysis, context-free, reference-request, runtime-analysis, parsers

What are some examples of context-free grammars that necessarily trigger cubic worst-case complexity for GLR parsers?

I have seen a mention of the example S $\rightarrow$ SSS | SS | "a" but I would be interested to find more information on this and also find proofs of their worst-case complexity. Can anyone refer to papers that would cover this?